# Search for text in files of same name in multiple folders of various depths

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

**Situation:** In Linux, I have a parent folder with almost 100 folders of various names. Each  folder has a file `ResourceParent.xml` and hundreds of of different version numbers each of which has its own `ResourceVer.xml` file. I am interested in both `ResourceParent.xml` in the 1st level folder and the ResourceVer.xml in the LATEST version folder (highest number) e.g. `ver548`.

I need to search inside each file for 3 tags `.txt|.csv|.xls` and return the information inside these tags into a report.txt file. The tags usually on the same line so I think Grep is ok.

**What I've tried:**

```
grep -nr -E ".txt|.csv|.xls" . > /dir/to/the/ReportFile.txt
```

This takes way too long as it searches in every one of the thousands of directories and produces a lot of unnecessary duplicated data.

Also, I've tried to go into each folder depending on what I'm looking for and running this script, which is a bit better re reduced duplicates and more relevant data, but it is still too cumbersome.

**Question:** How do I run a linux script to search for tags in a file structure that looks like this:
Tags of interest inside .xml files:

```
".txt|.csv|.xls"
```

current location:

```
/dir
```

File of interest 1:

```
/dir/par/ResourceParent.xml
```

File of interest 2:

(need the latest ver number)

```
/dir/par/ver###/ResourceVer.xml
```

Needed output file:

```
ResourceReport.txt
```

**Update**

I found `ls | tail -1` selects the folder with the greatest ver number. So I think the answer involves this..

Comment: Can't solve your entire problem, but this should do for your "grep"-problem: 
`find . -type f \( -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.xls" \)` or rather `find . -type f \( -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.xls" \) > /dir/to/the/ReportFile.txt` If you want the full path you could change the `.` to `/dir/to/the/ReportFile/`. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Patient32Bit I think the suffixes are in the text in the files, not in their names

Comment: @Zanna That is correct - I need to get those ".csv" etc strings that exist inside the file

Comment: @Patient32Bit another part of my project includes an issue that your suggestion resolves I think! In this issue there is no consistent levels of folder structure but there are similarities with folder names and file names at the end of each branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps with two commands...

```
grep --include="ResourceParent.xml" -r -E '.txt|.csv|.xls' > file
for d in par*; a=("$d"/*); b=($(sort -V <<<"${a[*]}")); grep -HE '.txt|.csv|.xls' "${b[@]: -1}"/*; done >> file
```

The second one puts the contents of each directory at the `par` level into an array sorted by version number so that you can search just the last item in the array. This seems to work (I am getting the last version number) and only takes a couple of seconds on my test directory structure (the first command takes about twice as long).

If your version numbers are padded so that they sort naturally, for the second command you would be able to use simply:

```
for d in par*; a=("$d"/*); grep -HE '.txt|.csv|.xls' "${a[@]: -1}"/*; done >> file
```

I mean if your numbers are `ver1` `ver2` ... `ver100`, you will need to sort the array, but if they are `ver001`, `ver002` ... `ver100`, you will not need to sort the array because it will be in the right order anyway.

You may need to replace `"${b[@]: -1}"/*` with `"${b[@]: -1}"/ResourceVer.xml`. I did not create other files. You will presumably also need to replace `par*` with something (I think you said you have about 100 directories at this level).

But maybe you wanted the data sorted by the directories at the level of `par` so that you get

```
data from par1/ResourceParent.xml
data from par1/ver{latest}/ResourceVer.xml
data from par2/ResourceParent/xml
data from par2/ver{latest}/ResourceVer.xml
```

You could perform some text processing on the output file, but it depends how your `par` directories are named. Since I named them `par1` `par2` ... `par200`

```
sort -V file >> betterfile
```

will to do that job, assuming filenames had no newlines.

You could also trim off the filenames by using `grep -h` (instead of `-H`) in the original commands (though that would mean that you could not sort the data afterwards by the above method), or by text processing at the end, for example, if your filenames have no colons or newlines this would be quite reliable:

```
sed 's/^[^:]*://' file
```

You can write to the file instead of stdout by adding the `-i` flag to `sed` after testing.

---

*Thanks to [John1024](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/53604/john1024) whose [answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181071/165104) provides a great way to get the last filename that doesn't rely on parsing the output of `ls` or `find` or gratuitously loop over the structure to count iterations.*

Comment: The version folders do have ver001, ver002 etc. There seems to be no more than 999 anywhere but given enough years it'll get there I think?

Comment: @Joe haha I suppose so. I think the shorter command should work until then. But I have assumed that your structure has consistent depth levels and I will have to rethink if it does not... I think recursive globbing should fix it...

Comment: Actually the structure is not consistent. However, my approach was to start simple and solve one problem at a time like this one haha. I was going to just navigate to the folder after which has consistent structure and run the commands. I'll get into this later for testing.. :-)

Comment: @Joe if the higher version number directories are newer, you can use `find` which looks at the metadata. It might be slow but it will be reliable. I haven't been able to sort the array with various levels and numbers  though I can try to figure it out